# Azure Application Gateway CookieBasedAffinity not sending sessions to same host

Tags: azure, load-balancing, sticky-sessions

We have deployed 2 Linux VMs in a Backend Pool behind an Application Gateway. Our application on the 2 Linux VMs requires that the session remain on the same backend server, but we are seeing a session use both backend servers.

We are not seeing any outages on the backend servers.

We have the CookieBasedAffinity setting enabled.

Why isn't this working as we expect and what could be the problem?

**UPDATE 1:**
Our app is called from another website but I don't see the Application Gateway cookie session value set, only our cookie values. Starting to suspect this is the issue...

**UPDATE 2:**
I no longer believe the issue described (badly) in Update 1 is the problem. Using Fiddler, I was able to see the cookie values in the call to my URL that was made and it contains the values for my app plus the `ApplicationGatewayAffinity=` value. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Did you find the solution for your problem? Can Application gateway use cookies that is created by a web-app?

Comment: No, in the end we switched to a Load Balancer. This isn't as nice in my opinion as you cannot see the status of health probes and logs aren't as good, but it works as intended and that was enough for us to change over to it.